# cgi error: TypeError: not indexable

Tags: python, cgi, typeerror

I want my python cgi script to receive parameters from an HTTP request. However, when I execute the request I get TypeError:

```
[Fri Jan 05 11:04:14.541250 2018] [cgid:error] [pid 23983:tid 139869410019072] [client xx.xxx.xx.xxx:yyyyy] End of script output before headers: parameters_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "path/to/script.py", line 18, in <module>
low_value = arguments.getvalue("low_value")
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/cgi.py", line 612, in getvalue
if key in self:
File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/cgi.py", line 652, in __contains__
raise TypeError("not indexable")
TypeError: not indexable
```

I send parameters to a python script via an ajax `GET` request as follows:

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
       $.ajax({
        url: "path/to/script.py",
        data: {
          "low_value": 500,
          "high_value": 4000
        },
        type: "GET",
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
     });
</script>
```

I try to receive the parameters with the following python script:

```
#! /path/to/python
import cgi

arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
low_value = arguments.getvalue("low_value")
high_value = arguments.gervalue("high_value")
```

It is clear that the error arises at `low_value = arguments.getvalue("low_value")`. Can someone explain why this error happens? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/path/to/python

import cgi
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

arguments = cgi.FieldStorage()
low_value = arguments.getvalue("low_value")
high_value = arguments.getvalue("high_value")

print("Content-type: text/html")
print()
print("High value: " + high_value + "Low value: " + low_value)
```

Hit that from the browser and any error/s will be shown.